# Sudoku 9x9 GUI Grid Python/Tkinter Buttons

Tags: python, button, tkinter, sudoku

I am creating a Sudoku GUI on Tkinter Python. Almost finished but what I want to happen is that when you click on a button (a single square in the 9x9 grid) that is a 0 (a number in the grid that wasn't previously set at the start (an empty gap that I've assigned as red 0s)) for it to increase by 1. So if you click this 4 times it becomes the number 4. (you may want to refer mainly to ----Main Code--- at the bottom)

```
from tkinter import *
import random
frame=Tk()
menu=Menu(frame)
file=Menu(menu)
file.add_command(label="Exit", command=frame.quit)
file.add_command(label="EASY LEVEL", command=lambda:easyLvl())
file.add_command(label="EASY LEVEL SOLVED", command=lambda:easyLvlSolved())
file.add_command(label="HARD LEVEL", command=lambda:hardLvl())
file.add_command(label="EASY LEVEL SOLVED", command=lambda:hardLvlSolved())


menu.add_cascade(label="Choose Level (Easy or Hard)", menu=file)
frame.config(menu=menu)
listofnumbers0=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

hardUnsolved=[8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,3,6,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,7,0,0,9,0,2,0,0,
    0,5,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,4,5,7,0,0,
    0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,0,
    0,0,1,0,0,0,0,6,8,
    0,0,8,5,0,0,0,1,0,
    0,9,0,0,0,0,4,0,0]

hardSolved=[8, 1, 2, 7, 5, 3, 6, 4, 9,
9, 4, 3, 6, 8, 2, 1, 7, 5,
6, 7, 5, 4, 9, 1, 2, 8, 3,
1, 5, 4, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 6,
3, 6, 9, 8, 4, 5, 7, 2, 1,
2, 8, 7, 1, 6, 9, 5, 3, 4,
5, 2, 1, 9, 7, 4, 3, 6, 8,
4, 3, 8, 5, 2, 6, 9, 1, 7,
7, 9, 6, 3, 1, 8, 4, 5, 2]

easyUnsolved=[5,1,7,6,0,0,0,3,4,
               2,8,9,0,0,4,0,0,0,
               3,4,6,2,0,5,0,9,0,
               6,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,
               0,3,8,0,0,6,0,4,7,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,9,0,0,0,0,0,7,8,
               7,0,3,4,0,0,5,6,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
easySolved=[5,1,7,6,9,8,2,3,4,
             2,8,9,1,3,4,7,5,6,
             3,4,6,2,7,5,8,9,1,
             6,7,2,8,4,9,3,1,5,
             1,3,8,5,2,6,9,4,7,
             9,5,4,7,1,3,6,8,2,
             4,9,5,3,6,2,1,7,8,
             7,2,3,4,8,1,5,6,9,
             8,6,1,9,5,7,4,2,3]
i=0
q=0
thelist=[listofnumbers0,easyUnsolved, easySolved,hardUnsolved, hardSolved]

def easyLvl():
    global q
    q=1
    createGrid()

def easyLvlSolved():
    global q
    q=2
    createGrid()

def hardLvl():
    global q
    q=3
    createGrid()
def hardLvlSolved():
    global q
    q=4
    createGrid()

def btnCommand(x):
    if x==0:
        x=x+1





colourTxt="black"
#-----------------------------MAIN CODE------------------
def createGrid():
    for rowindex in range (9):
        for colindex in range (9):
            if (rowindex in (0,1,2,6,7,8) and colindex in (3,4,5) or \
                (rowindex in (3,4,5) and colindex in (0,1,2,6,7,8))):
                    colour="light blue"
            else:
                colour="white"

            global i
            x=thelist[q][i]
            i=i+1
            if i==81:
                i=0

            if x==0:
                colourTxt="red"
            else:
                colourTxt="black" 
            btn=Button(frame, width=8, height=4, bg=colour, text=x, fg=colourTxt, command=lambda:btnCommand(x))   
            btn.grid(row=rowindex, column=colindex, sticky=N+S+E+W)


            btn.grid(row=rowindex, column=colindex, sticky=N+S+E+W)
createGrid()
frame.mainloop()
```

Comment: Typo on line 10: the string should be hard level solved.

Comment: cheers.Changed that now

Comment: This is too much code. Please reduce it down to a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

In the below code the button cycles through the decimal numerals except for 0, which are basically sudoku numbers, for a `widget`'s text:

```
import tkinter as tk


def cycle(widget):
    widget['text'] = (widget['text'] % 9) + 1

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text=1)
btn['command'] = lambda widget=btn: cycle(widget)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix your lambda values in the button callback, this is the main change that I added to your code. All other edits are mainly to make the code clearer and remove all unnecessary parts.

Take home message ist here, that you are basically always using the last iterator value for the callback function of `Button(command=...)`, if you're not fixing the values you pass to you lambda function. This addition of `row=rowindex,...` forces Python to look back/save the values while create the buttons.

```
import numpy as np

hardUnsolved=np.array([[8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],...])

def btnCommand(row, col, x):
    x += 1
    hardUnsolved[row][col] = x
    createGrid()

#-----------------------------MAIN CODE------------------
def createGrid():
    for rowindex in range (9):
        for colindex in range (9):
            if ((rowindex in (0,1,2,6,7,8) and colindex in (3,4,5)) or \
                rowindex in (3,4,5) and colindex in (0,1,2,6,7,8))):
                colour='blue'
            else:
                colour='white'

        x=hardUnsolved[rowindex][colindex]

        if x==0:
            colourTxt='red'
        else:
            colourTxt='black'

        btn=Button(frame, width=4, height=3, bg=colour, text=x, fg=colourTxt, 
            command=lambda row=rowindex, col=colindex, x=x: btnCommand(row, col, x))
        btn.grid(row=rowindex, column=colindex, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        btn.grid(row=rowindex, column=colindex, sticky=N+S+E+W)

    mainloop()

createGrid()
```

*Edit: I also imported `numpy` so that the assignment of values to your grid is a little bit more intuitive and clean.*

Comment: receiving an error on line x=hardUnsolved[rowindex][colindex] that states int object is not subscriptable?

Comment: you have to `import numpy as np` at the beginning and define your sudokus as `np.array([[...],[...],...])`.

Comment: Please consider closing the thread since your original question is answered.